# Make v-col height equal to parent v-row

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have a v-row made up of 3 columns, the first of which contains an image making it the tallest. The row's height matches that of the image (and thereby the first column), but the other two columns are only as tall as their contents.

```
<v-row justify="center">
    <v-col cols="4" class="pb-0 pt-0 pl-3" align-self="center">
        <v-img src="..." />
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="6" class="pb-0 pr-6 pt-0" align-self="center">
        <v-row>
            <p>New Product</p>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
            <small>Product Name</small>
        </v-row>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2" align-self="center">
        <p>B001</p>
    </v-col>
```

I need the final column to fill the height. Giving the col `height: 100%` only works if I give the v-row a fixed height value which I don't want to do as the contents can change in size. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you remove align-self="center" attribute from v-col. I guess it will solve your problem?

Comment: @PrakashRajotiya This causes the column to vertically align to the top of the row, not to adjust its height unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Add `align="stretch"` to `v-row` so all the nested columns fill the height of the row.